# How to count the number of text reoccurence from a grid after searching using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

From my application, I search for a name, the result opens in new window with the relevant employees in a grid, I need to know the number of occurences from that grid of that name.
Like if search for John results - John Fernandes, John Maxwell and John D souza. result sshould be 3 John's found.

This does not work:

```
    WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.tagName("text"));
        String bodytext=text.getText();
        System.out.println(bodytext);

  //Verify the Name searched        
  int count=0;

  while (bodytext.contains(name)){
        count++;

        bodytext=bodytext.substring(bodytext.indexOf(name))+name.length();
  }
```

Comment: What error did you get? and looking at `WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.tagName("text"));` I don't think, html pages have `text` as a tagname. Can you please provide html code snippet for one of the mathching names?

Comment: This is confusing. What's all this substring about? What are you intending to do? What doesn't it (your code above) do? Aren't these names within elements? Like in a table? You appear to be searching the entire document for a piece of text and then cannot understand how you get from there to another piece. This shows you lack some understanding of how the DOM & the page fits together. You don't just search the entire body for a bit of text.

Comment: It should be better to provide the solution, if you provide the HTML code also.

Comment: Well it got working, the only problem was bodytext=bodytext.substring(bodytext.indexOf(name)+name.length());

Answer (score 0):

get the path to the grid ex.

```
WebElements gridElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='grid1']/tr/td"));
system.out.println("No. of occ. is->"+gridElements.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

`By.tagName("text")` will not work as "text" is not the HTML Tag name.

Use XPATH or better is CSS Selector.
You can use javascript also to count the number of names it returned.

If you can give the result page HTML I can help you in finding CSS Selectore or Javascript that can return you the result.

Comment: Yes, "text" was by mistake, corrected it. And added "body" as tagname, but I dont get any error, and its prints the body at System.out.println(bodytext);

Comment: As due to security reasons I cant provide the complete html snippet, but here is one of the grid element

Comment: Let's take table example on http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp  below javascript will give number of rows in table                                                               document.getElementsByClassName('reference')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr').length

Answer (score 0):

Well it got working, the only problem was

bodytext=bodytext.substring(bodytext.indexOf(name)+name.length());

Answer (score -1):

Let's take example from page http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Here is javascript code for getting rows in table (It included heading row also)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('reference')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr').length
```

To run the javascript from web driver use

```
(String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('reference')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr').length");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This can be done using native Selenium methods. C#: `driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("reference").FindElements(By.TagName("tr")).Count()`. JS is not required here, at all.

Comment: You are correct it can be done through the mentioned way but javascript can also be used.                         I am not sure if selenium is running similar javascript in background but running javascript we can get result in single call.